# How to get Multiple data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is the controller im getting error Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
public function showcustom($id)
        {

            $custompack = CustomPackages::find($id);
            $venue = Venue::find($custompack->venue);

            $food = Food::all();
            $attire = Attire::all();
            $hairmakeup = HairMakeup::all();
            $invitation = Invitation::all();
            $photosvideos = PhotosVideos::all();
            $cakescupcakes = CakesCupcakes::all();
            $lightsound = LightSound::all();
            $programhost = ProgramHost::all();
            $eventsingers = EventSingers::all();
            //$custompack = CustomPackages::all();

            return view('packages.customshow',compact('venue','custompack','packages','food','attire','hairmakeup','photosvideos','cakescupcakes','lightsound','programhost','eventsingers','invitation'));
}
```

Comment: There isn't much to really go on here... Where is $key being defined? Where is this error occuring?

Comment: Which file/line throws this error? where is `$key` defined? From your code we can't guess anything

Comment: <img src="{{asset('images/' . $venue->image)}}"> in this line of code  im getting error @Adam

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the venue you are passing in `Venue::find(integer_expected)` is an integer..